# eclipse plugin to create a customized welcome screen

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on a eclipse based application . I need to develop a plugin which will create a new welcome screen which will be rendered when the user opens the application .This new screen will have a list of options for the user to perform.

The  requirement where in when I click on the link, it will lead me to a sign up page and once logged in I will get a response which I need to save on the disk.The response should not be visible on the screen.

I am able to get the welcome page up with the links, but clicking on the link would open the sign up page in the browser and once logged in would display the response in the web view . 
Is there a way to show a custom response to the user once he logs in and capture the api response in the background?

Any insights on how this can be done will be very helpful.

Comment: The 'User assistance support' section of the 'Platform Plug-in Developer Guide' in the Eclipse help covers this in detail.

Comment: thanks greg, I am now able to display a custom link on the welcome page. I have a requirement where in when I click on the link, it will lead me to a sign up page and once logged in I will get a response which I need to save on the disk.The response should not be visible on the screen. As per the current approach, clicking on the link would open the sign up page in the browser and once logged in would display the responce in the web view . Is there a way to show a custom response to the user once he logs in and capture the api response in the background?